# encrypted disk mounting error after fresh install of Debian 10 on THinpad 7th gen

Tags: system-installation

I installed Debian on my 7th gen Thinkpad according to the following guide: https://wiki.debian.org/SetupGuides/SecurePersonalComputer

To summarize:

- I wiped my disk with System Rescue.
- I forced UEFI
  *Select "Guided - use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM" (or "Manual").
- Select Separate home partition
- I used max space for guided partitioning

The desktop environment is KDE.

Everything went fine and I can start up but there seems to be a mounting issue, please see the screenshot:

[image]

I reinstalled the system without separating the home partition and got the same error.

The current ouptut of `lsblk` is:

```
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM    SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sda                    8:0    0  238.5G  0 disk
├─sda1                 8:1    0    512M  0 part   /boot/efi
├─sda2                 8:2    0    244M  0 part   /boot
└─sda3                 8:3    0  237.8G  0 part
  └─sda3_crypt       254:0    0  237.7G  0 crypt
    ├─tp1--vg-root   254:1    0    230G  0 lvm    /
    └─tp1--vg-swap_1 254:2    0    7.7G  0 lvm    [SWAP]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: this is what I found so far, unfortunately not very helpful https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/+bug/1762307

Comment: Thank you for posting a new, focused question. Please, add the output of `lsblk` to make others aware of the disks, partitions and mount points on our system. Also, does the error shown in the screenshot happen when you click on the "home" directory? Are you logged in as a regular user (i.e. non-root)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
The error appears when I click on "Encrypted Drive" under "Devices" 
No error when I click on "home".
I am logged in as a regular user and did not set a root pw.
Here is the result from lsblk:
[link](https://ibb.co/tMSLj2G)

Comment: Is that one the only error you get in relation to accessing your storage? That is not an issue—more will come as an answer, especially if you also share the output of `lsblk`, or something equivalent (you can of course obfuscate part of it if you feel you need to).

Comment: it is not an issue? so I can continue and install everything else? That is good to hear thanks. Lsblk is shared above under "link"

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is not an issue. Dolphin (KDE's file manager) is simply including in the "Devices" section of the "Places" panel a device that happens to be a container for other devices. ("Devices", here, refers to block devices as seen by the kernel, not to physical ones).

The "237.7 GiB Encrypted Drive" is what `lsblk` lists as `sda3_crypt` (a Physical Volume (in LVM parlance) used by LVM as the underlying storage for the Logical Volumes `tp1--vg-root` and `tp1--vg-swap_1`). It doesn't directly contain a file system and is thus not accessible by means of a file manager. Instead, it contains the 230 GiB Logical Volume `tp1--vg-root`, which in turn contains the file system mounted as `/` and can be (is) accessed by your applications, including Dolphin.

You may be able to verify this. The command

```
udisksctl info --object-path block_devices/dm_2d0
```

(note that `block_devices/dm_2d0` comes from the error message in your screenshot) should show `/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt` as "PreferredDevice" and `LVM2_member` as "IdType". In contrast, the device mounted on `/`, which holds all of your data, likely has `/dev/mapper/tp1--vg-root` as "PreferredDevice" and a file system type (e.g. ext4) as "IdType" (you should be able to locate it by skimming through the output of `udisksctl dump`).

I would suggest you to simply right click on that "237.7 GiB Encrypted Drive" and hide it (you will be able to see it again by right-clicking on "Devices" and selecting "Show Hidden Places"). You will never need to manually deal with it.

Comment: thank you so much I will try that!
And can you please tell me where Debian installs new software? I want to know where I should best extract and keep software I got from outside sources. THank you very much°

Comment: @Debiannewb01 I don't have a reference at hand, but software that is not installed by means of a package manager should be placed in `/usr/local`. I believe Debian guides would suggest creating your own packages instead of directly installing locally compiled software, though this would likely be overkill for most users.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much for your help.m I could verify everything and hide the volume as suggested